# Merging two dictionaries as rows into one pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My question is similar to

[Merging two dictionaries into one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561337/merging-two-dictionaries-into-one-dataframe)

but that question asked how to merge two dictionaries into one DataFrame, using the dictionaries as columns. In my case, the dictionaries are the rows of the DataFrame.

For example for these dictionaries:

```py
foo = {'mean': 0.11, 'median': 0.09, 'p90': 0.24}
bar = {'mean': 0.10, 'median': 0.09, 'p90': 0.20}
```

I want a DataFrame like this:

```
    set mean median  p90
    foo 0.11   0.09 0.24
    bar 0.10   0.09 0.20
```

How can I create it?

Comment: `pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(foo, index=['foo']), pd.DataFrame(bar, index=['bar'])))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do

```
d = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
pd.DataFrame(d).T.rename_axis('set').reset_index()
```

Alternative approach with comprehension

```
d = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
pd.DataFrame({'set': k, **v} for k, v in d.items())
```

---

```
   set  mean  median   p90
0  foo  0.11    0.09  0.24
1  bar  0.10    0.09  0.20
```

Comment: @DeltaIV You can simply reset the index `.reset_index()`

Comment: thanks! Accepted. Just a clarification: what's the meaning of writing `{'set': k, **v}` in the approach based on dictionary comprehension?

Comment: @DeltaIV `**` is an unpacking operator, in this case `**` unpacks the dictionary and merges it with the enclosing dictionary. For example, lets say `a = {'x': 10}` and `b = {'y': 11, 'z': 12}`, now when you do `{**a, **b}` this will result in `{'x': 10, 'y': 11, 'z': 12}`